# Resolve dependency by ninject "ToProvider" method, which is based on HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have layered asp.net MVC application. My application has following architecture:

1. DomainLayer, which contains domain objects
2. DAL (repository pattern), has reference only to DomainLayer
3. BLL, has reference to DomainLayer and DAL
4. PresentationLayer(Web), has reference to DamainLayer and BLL

And I have separate layer(let's call it DependencyResolver), which is responsible for resolving dependencies through all application layers. I use Ninject dependency resolver. This project has references to DomainLayer, DAL and BLL

I need to resolve dependencies of some object in different ways based on logged user role. For example I have 2 implementations of the same IOrderRepository: OrderSQLRepository and OrderMemoryRepository:

For UserRole.Admin I have to call

```
Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderSQLRepository>();
```

And for other users I need to bind interface to IOrderMemoryRepository which accepts the Session as constructor argument, to store values temporary in session.

```
Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderMemoryRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("pSession", HttpContext.Current.Session);
```

So as there is conditional case, I use ToProvider method:

```
Bind<IOrderRepository>().ToProvider<OrderRepositoryProvider>();

public class OrderRepositoryProvider : IProvider
    {
        public Type Type { get { return typeof(IOrderRepository); } }
        public object Create(IContext context)
        {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return context.Kernel.Get<OrderMemoryRepository>(new ConstructorArgument("pSession", HttpContext.Current.Session["Orders"]));
                }

        return context.Kernel.Get<OrderSQLRepository>();
    }
}
```

But as the bindings are perforemed in separate project, which does not have reference to System.Web.Mvc namespace, I couldn't use HttpContext.Current.

So what would you suggest, am I in right direction or should I use different approach or if the direction is right, how can I pass the HttpContext.Current to Load() method of NinjectModule or to OrderRepositoryProvider

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, however, typically in a web application the web layer is the composition root (contains all your bindings) because it is the entry point into the app. in other words, put all your bindings into the web layer as NinjectModules.

Additionally, you may consider creating wrappers for the HttpContext values you want to use. for example, `IHttpContext` that implements a getter for `HttpContext.Current.User` and then use the interface in your provider instead of the concrete `HttpContext.Current`. I would do the same for retrieving the orders from session, i.e., `ISessionOrders` and then Ninject would be able to resolve the dependency for `OrderMemoryRepository` without a constructor argument.

so then you would have:

```
public object Create(IContext context)
{
    if (context.Kernel.Get<IHttpContext>().User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return context.Kernel.Get<OrderMemoryRepository>();
    }

    return context.Kernel.Get<OrderSQLRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point that my bindings along with NinjectModules are separated from web layer, is the requirement, that the web layer must not know anything about DAL. If I move the bindings to web layer, I also will be forced to add DAL reference to web layer :( How can I overcome this?

The advice about wrappers I will obviously follow.